# Group by boolean value but change key in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm sorting an array by the before attribute which is a boolean, this works but I'd rather not use true and false as the hash values and use 'before' when true and 'after' when before equals false

```
a.each { |x| arr << x.answers.group_by(&:before) unless x.answers == nil }
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

i.e instead of having  `true: [], false: []`
I'd prefer to have `before: [], after: []`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure like this

```
x.answers.group_by {|e| e.before ? :before : :after}
```

this will create a `Hash` of `{before: [],after:[]}`

eg.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a.group_by {|n| n.odd? ? :odd : :even} 
#=> {odd: [1, 3, 5, 7], even: [2, 4, 6]}
```

`#group_by` works on the return response from the block so `true` and `false` become keys but you can replace the response with anything you like and these will act as the keys instead. This means you could have more than 2 returns e.g.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a.group_by {|n| n == 2 ? :two : n == 3 ? :three : n.odd? ? :odd : :even} 
#=> {:odd=>[1, 5, 7], :two=>[2], :three=>[3], :even=>[4, 6]}
```

I used ternary operators to save space I would not recommend nesting them this deep as it takes away from readability this was just an example.